# `runtime/trace` viewer on browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, go, trace

when i run `go tool trace m.trace`
it opens this link `http://127.0.0.1:37721/trace`

on both chrome & firefox i go an empty page

in chrome Console i found 
[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJhMK.png)

> GET http://127.0.0.1:37721/trace_viewer_html 404 (Not Found)
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: tr is not defined

i found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510046/how-do-i-view-the-details-of-a-trace-produced-by-runtime-trace) talk about issue in firefox and chrome version 
i use **ubuntu16.04/chrome66.0/golang1.10**

1. so what should i do to be able to view the trace
2. is there is an online tool could i upload my m.trace file to browse online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was "I install Go from your OS package manager"

after reinstalling Go following [official instructions](https://golang.org/doc/install) the problem solved

you can find more in issue created with golang repo [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/25151)